# Compilation error in C++ Qt creator project

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to programming. I downloaded Qt project repository from Git hub and tried to build it on my Ubuntu 14.04. I got some errors when I tried to compile it. I'm using Qt5 and the project file is at least 5 year old.
Code is as below,

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "mainwindow.h"        
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
showMaximized();
A = new FiniteElements;
B = new QwtBeginner;
browseButton = createButton(tr("&Open"), SLOT(browse()));

QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;

mainLayout->addWidget(B, 0, 0);
mainLayout->addWidget(browseButton, 0, 1);

setLayout(mainLayout);

setWindowTitle(tr("L4V14_oapsois by Mikhail Krishtop"));
}

void MainWindow::browse()
{
QString filepath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Select input      datafile"),QDir::currentPath());

if (!filepath.isEmpty()) {
    std::string str = std::string(filepath.toAscii().data());
    const char * stuff = str.c_str();
    A->SetFN(stuff);
    A->evaluate();
           B->eval(A->GetXArray(),A->GetYArray(),A->GetN(),A->GetTriangles(),stuff,
            A->GetTArray(),A->GetX(),A->GetY(),A->GetResultTemp());
}
}

QPushButton *MainWindow::createButton(const QString &text, const char *member)
{
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(text);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, member);
return button;
}
```

I got the following errors,
**error: QGridLayout was not declared in this space

error: QFileDialog has not been declared

error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QPushButton'**

Could anyone help me?
                                               ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a number of includes, note that `QtGui` does not provide you with `QGridLayout`, `QFileDialog` or `QPushButton`. According to the Qt documentation:

> The Qt GUI module provides classes for windowing system integration,
>   event handling, OpenGL and OpenGL ES integration, 2D graphics,
>   imaging, fonts and typography. These classes are used internally by
>   Qt's user interface technologies and can also be used directly, for
>   instance to write applications using low-level OpenGL ES graphics
>   APIs.

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-module.html#details) for a full overview of the classes which are included with QtGui. Hence in conclusion, as pointed out Thx. @HAG, you need add the following includes:

```
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
```

Alternatively you can just include the `QtWidgets` class, which will provide you with all of these classes.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
```

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html#details), for a full overview of the classes which are available by including `QtWidgets`.

Comment: Thanks  @Gio. It worked.   But I got another error message as,       error: 'class QString' has no member named 'toAscii'. Can you solve it

                                                ^

Comment: @user294664, please provide credit for helpful answers. I recommend you that when working with Qt, always have the documentation open to check things. E.g. a QString has no member named 'toAscii', exactly as your error message says, you can check that by looking at the QString documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html).

Comment: ,Sorry. I didn't understand the credit system you mentioned since I'm new to stackoverflow. I haven't understand the techniques for writing a good programme yet. I have asked another question on qmake. Could you please try it?

Answer (score 3):

Try to include the missing headers

```
    #include <QGridLayout>
    #include <QFileDialog>
    #include <QPushButton>
```